# How to fix the Xilinx Warning Xst:2117?

Tags: warnings, xilinx, synthesis, xilinx-ise

The following is the exact statement of the warning:

> Xst:2117 - HDL ADVISOR - Mux Selector "state" of Case statement
>   line XX was re-encoded using one-hot encoding. The case statement
>   will be optimized (default statement optimization), but this
>   optimization may lead to design initialization problems. To ensure the
>   design works safely, you can: - add an 'INIT' attribute on signal
>    (optimization is then done without any risk) - use the
>   attribute 'signal_encoding user' to avoid onehot optimization - use
>   the attribute 'safe_implementation yes' to force XST to perform a safe
>   (but less efficient) optimization

I have already encoded my states using one-hot encoding. I have also tried changing the FSM Encoding Style to "User" in the HDL options of the process properties but I am still getting this Info. Should I just ignore this Info? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your FSM really recognized as an FSM or as plain logic? Do you see an FSM report?

Comment: Where can I check that?

Comment: Just search your synthesis report (*.syr file) or in the GUI for the word "FSM". You'll find state encoding tables, otherwise it hasn't recognized your FSM.

Comment: I am unable to find state encoding tables. Following are the related HDL Options:                                                                                           ---- Source Options
Top Module Name                    : Top
Automatic FSM Extraction           : YES
FSM Encoding Algorithm             : Auto
Safe Implementation                : No
FSM Style                          : lut

Comment: If you don't see tables like on [that webpage](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/fpga/fsm_optimization/), then you don't have coded your FSMs in a right way.